# colcon can not find my package

Tags: c++, cmake

I have been writing some ROS2 code in C++ using colcon on Ubuntu 20.04, all has been working fine, up until now. colcon all of a sudden started complaining that it couldn't find my packages. When I run `colcon build --packages-select test` I get the following error

```
WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:ignoring unknown package 'test' in --packages-select
```

My test package is still in the `~ros/dev_ws/src` directory. If I create a new package (`test2` say), I can build it without error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by a cut and paste error in the package.xml file. I had copied some older source code and didn't update the package.xml project property